# android : TextInputLayout hides drawableRight of child EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

I am always updated with library updates, and this is what it resulted into.

In build.gradle(Project:xxx):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
```

In build.gradle(Module:app)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

And put password field as below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Taadaa...My Password field looks now as below:

[image]

You can also go simply with `EditText`.

But, there are some glitches in this update.

**Problem:**
If I put any drawableRight in EditText, it displays nothing. TextInputLayout also has property to disable toggle functionality. I did it that too as below, but no success:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_alarm_on_black_24dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: File a bug here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Support%20Library%20bug

Comment: I'm having the same issues...drawableStart doesn't work either.  The error indicators show up multiple times also...I rolled back to 24.1.1

Comment: @JayPaulynice yup.. I too had to roll back version to 24.1.1

Comment: I, too, have encountered this issue. Rolling back to 24.1.1 :-(

Comment: this was a bug [check](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220305) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220728) but resolved in update of **24.2.1 of the support library**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported the issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221002.

It was a bug in the library version `24.2.0` but it has been fixed in version `24.2.1`. Simply update as below:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to upgrade the support library to 24.2.1 (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221002).