# Updating appcompat-v7 and design libraries to v24.2.0 cause bugs

Tags: java, android

I used appcompat-v7 and design libraries with v24.1.1 and the project works as expected without any problem or bug. But when I update these two libraries to v24.2.0, some bugs appears.

**1.** The first bug with the appcompat-v7 library, after I update this library, the Toolbar and FAB goes away in the design screen. Also, when I run the project, my Android app stops (Force Close) after launching the app immediately. **The Log:**

```
09-03 14:02:56.543 14932-14932/com.twitter.i_droidi.notah E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.twitter.i_droidi.notah, PID: 14932
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twitter.i_droidi.notah/net.alhazmy13.catcho.library.CatchoReportActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at net.alhazmy13.catcho.library.CatchoReportActivity.onCreate(CatchoReportActivity.java:32)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at net.alhazmy13.catcho.library.CatchoReportActivity.onCreate(CatchoReportActivity.java:32) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at net.alhazmy13.catcho.library.CatchoReportActivity.onCreate(CatchoReportActivity.java:32) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/widget/ImageView;Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager;)V in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper' appears in /data/data/com.twitter.i_droidi.notah/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-24.2.0_6745dad81260adbd6a3e5cd1e754bd0f70ca1f25-classes.dex)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:170)
                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:147)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at net.alhazmy13.catcho.library.CatchoReportActivity.onCreate(CatchoReportActivity.java:32) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**2.** The second bug with the design library, after I update this library, the whole TextInputLayout and EditText goes away, and I can not write anything in the EditText area.

*** Update: The XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".CreateNote"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout_create_note">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llmain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputlayoutTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/create_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/note_title"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="19.5sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#212121"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:tag="text_color|primary_text_inverse,text_size|title"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/save"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:tag="bg_tint_accent_color_selector_lighter"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputlayoutContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="17dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterTextAppearance="@style/MyCounterTextStyle" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/create_body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/note_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:tag="tint_accent_color,text_primary,textsize_subheading"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:fontFamily="serif" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please share your xml file ?

Comment: Yes there are few bugs with latest support library. I also have one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164224/android-textinputlayout-hides-drawableright-of-child-edittext

Comment: Please share your layout file so that we can help you out.

Comment: @gaurav4sarma I added the XML file.

Comment: @ChintanSoni I added the XML file. And yeah, I think there are bugs in these two libraries.

Comment: FWIW, same problem here: AS2.2RC, and same versions as you for support and design. FAB is an amazingly broken piece of code; I think I'll probably just give up on it.

Answer (score 0):

update libraries to latest one as you see in .gradle file when you move the cursor on those libraries.

Always keep design library version greater than equal to app compat library as I did to resolve the same issue.
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**24.2.1'**
compile 'com.android.support:design:**24.2.1'**
from 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'